# How to take photo and upload firebase (Bitmap Image) android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have an app, I select a picture (gallery) and upload it to the firebase.
I want to upload a picture taken with a camera. Many attempts, then I could not upload.

1. I take a picture.
2. Add to bitmap.
3. At this time it writes that the "Select an image" (error in uploadImg.setOnClickListener).

Please help me:

1. Correct the code.
2. What code should I add to make the function work.

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; ///////
    private static final int MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE = 100;////
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
    {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
        {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "camera permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }




    Button chooseImg, uploadImg;
    ImageView imgView;
    int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 111;
    Uri filePath;
    ProgressDialog pd;
    EditText idEdtCourseName;

    //creating reference to firebase storage
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://example-10d12.appspot.com");   


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        chooseImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.chooseImg);
        uploadImg = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadImg);
        imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        idEdtCourseName = findViewById(R.id.EdtCourseName);

        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Uploading....");



        chooseImg.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
            }
            else
            {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });

        uploadImg.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if(filePath != null) {
                pd.show();
                String name = idEdtCourseName.getText().toString().trim();
                StorageReference childRef = storageRef.child(name);

                //uploading the image
                UploadTask uploadTask = childRef.putFile(filePath);

                uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        pd.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload Failed -> " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select an image", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            filePath = data.getData();

            try {
                //getting image from gallery
                Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

                //Setting image to ImageView
                imgView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you select a picture from the galery you get an uri which you use to upload the file. When you let a camera app take a picture the camera app will produce a file too for which you have an uri and even know the file path. I wonder what you need more. Where exactly do you have a problem?

Comment: Your camera intent only gives you a small thumbnail bitmap. No file. Do you only want a small thumbnail? Why not a normal image file?

Comment: I have a problem: uploadImg.setOnClickListener order. Can't see the picture in Bitmag( if(filePath != null),    Is always =null.    It was loading from the gallery when I was selecting, but when I moved to the camera it wrote an error.

Comment: Is this the solution? : Save the taken image and after upload it?

Comment: `Your camera intent only gives you a small thumbnail bitmap. No file.` So filePath==null.   `Do you only want a small thumbnail? Why not a normal image file?`

Comment: `Uri filePath;` Please don't name an uri a path. Makes your code unreadable. Better: `Uri fileUri;`.

Comment: What can I change to read and upload photo?     Uri filePath; -->>Uri fileUri;  only this?

Comment: `Your camera intent only gives you a small thumbnail bitmap. No file. So filePath==null. Do you only want a small thumbnail? Why not a normal image file?`

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I was uploading an image saved in bitmap, which as I find out is not recommended, I am currently taking a separate image with the camera and then uploading it.